# Attribute error in smtp

Tags: python, smtp, smtpclient, smtplib

I want to make use of SMTP. I have written a simple code that will
send mail from one mail address to another.

```
import smtplib
msg = "smtp_mail" 
server = smtplib.SMTP('MailServerAddress') 
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg) 
server.quit()
```

here I am getting an error `AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute
'find'`

Please help!!

Comment: Why do you call `smtplib.SMTP` twice? What are the values of fromaddr, toaddrs, and msg?

Comment: yes that was the error. got it too thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program crashes on line : server = smtplib.SMTP(server)

Just remove this line, it's twice !